# Why .bat file works and C# code doesn't work for folder mapping

Tags: c#, batch-file, mapping

I have written a code in C# to map a Drobo Drive to my machine, which doesn't work. but similar code lines used from bat file works and maps.

I am wondering if there is a difference in C# code and .bat file code which allows the code to work for mapping.

In the past I have also wrote code in C# that didn't work for moving files from Drobo, but a .bat file code worked.

Code from C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MapDrive
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Map Network drive
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

                psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";

                psi.Arguments = @"/C net use N: \\DroboNS2\Folder /USER:credentials /PERSISTENT:YES";

                psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                process.StartInfo = psi;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
                process.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error in mapping. Stack Trace: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

VB Code:

```
@echo off
net use N: \\DroboNS2\Folder /USER:Credentials /persistent:yes
```

Both the files (.exe and .bat) are put in the Startup folder and tested.

Comment: `net` is the process, you should be able to make `net` your `FileName` and everything else the arguments. Pretty sure I've seen this solve issues before where people attempt to use `cmd` to invoke commands when really the commands themselves are a process.

Comment: _"doesn't work"_ is a really weak problem description. What is the actual error message/result/behaviour you get?

Comment: net (or rather net.exe) is an executable. Executables can be directly executed. No need to execute cmd.exe just for letting cmd.exe execute net.exe since net.exe can be executed directly. (Yes, i came close to mentally executing myself by writing this comment ;-) )

Comment: Try following : psi.FileName = "c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";

Comment: I didn't know that  net is a process. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
using (Process process = Process.Start("net.exe", @"use N: \\DroboNS2\Folder /USER:credentials /PERSISTENT:YES"))
    process.WaitForExit();
```